# get only "google" from a full google url with subdomains in php

Tags: php

I used the code below to get "google" printed out

```
$domain = parse_url('http://google.com', PHP_URL_HOST);
$url = strstr($domain, ".", true);
echo $url;
```

Works fine as long the url is not like in.google.com (only "in" is printed now).
Is there a workaround?

Note: I need all extensions to be remove .com or .co or .anything

Comment: for `in.google.com`, do you still just need `google` or `in.google`?

Comment: @simon only "google" if possible

Comment: see my answer ^_^

Comment: @nandukk What if the URL is `images.google.co.uk`? I'm not sure that what you're looking for is possible for all cases.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use regexp instead. Both the following scripts returns "google" inside `$matches[1]`

with `in`

```
$regexp = "/([\w]{0,}).([\w]{2,3}|[\w]{2,3}.[\w]{2,3})$/";
$input = parse_url('http://in.google.com', PHP_URL_HOST);
preg_match($regexp, $input, $matches);
var_dump($matches[1]); // string(6) "google"
```

without `in`

```
$regexp = "/([\w]{0,}).([\w]{2,3}|[\w]{2,3}.[\w]{2,3})$/";
$input = parse_url('http://google.com', PHP_URL_HOST);
preg_match($regexp, $input, $matches);
var_dump($matches[1]); // string(6) "google"
```

As you can see in the following https://regex101.com's link

https://regex101.com/r/iVyzzw/1/:

[image]

it works. Always, in `$matches[1]`, you can find google.

Comment: This only works for `.com`.  OP said "I need all extensions to be remove .com or .co or .anything"

Comment: Since my answer would copy/paste yours, I'll just leave a comment ;-) Something like this would catch any tld and take care of some of the most common two-part suffices: `$regexp = "/([\w]{0,})(\.(edu|gov|net|mil|org|co|ac|ed|gv|gob))?\.[a-z0-9]+$/i";`. This won't be sufficient for the nightmare that is [`.aero`](https://github.com/publicsuffix/list/blob/master/public_suffix_list.dat#L36), but it's a start.

Comment: @sensorario Hi sorry for a (very) late response. I was busy with something else and could not verify this till now. I checked this and seems to work on every url that was submitted to my site (over 300). There might still be some  edge cases that i don't know about (i'll let you know if anything pops up). As of now, this seems correct.  Just integrated this to the site. Thanks :)